# JavsScript | Remove object from array

Tags: javascript

Hello Everyone I am a little bit stuck in my project , right now I successfully created a cart which I can add items , but now I am stuck because I cant figure out how to create a function that will remove specific item and not all the items from the cart.

```js
var products = [
  {
   name:"Gta",
   price:15,
   catagory:"Games",
   inCart:0
  },
  {
    name:"Call of Duty",
    price:15,
    catagory:"Games",
    inCart:0
  },
  {
    name:"Sims",
    price:15,
    catagory:"Games",
    inCart:0
   },
   {
    name:"Razor",
    price:15,
    catagory:"Games",
    inCart:0
   },
   {
    name:"Age of Empire",
    price:15,
    catagory:"Games",
    inCart:0
   },
   {
    name:"Drive license",
    price:15,
    catagory:"Games",
    inCart:0
   },
   {
    name:"Halo",
    price:15,
    catagory:"Games",
    inCart:0
   }
];
```

```js
function SetItem(product){

  let CartItems = localStorage.getItem("prodcutsInCart");
  CartItems = JSON.parse(CartItems);

  if(CartItems != null){
    if(CartItems[product.name] == undefined){
        CartItems = {
          ...CartItems,
          [product.name]:product
        }
     }
     CartItems[product.name].inCart +=1;
    }else{
      product.inCart = 1;
       CartItems = {
       [product.name]: product
        }

    }
    localStorage.setItem("prodcutsInCart",JSON.stringify(CartItems));
}
```

Also I am adding here the output on the localstorage under the key "ProductsInCart"

```js
{"undefined":{"name":"Call of Duty","price":15,"catagory":"Games","id":"id","inCart":3},"Call of Duty":{"name":"Call of Duty","price":15,"catagory":"Games","inCart":1}}
```

so basically I just try to figure out for example how I remove specific the Call of duty Game and not all the object under the key of  "ProductsInCart".

Comment: do you have to create the remove function yourself, because it seems to me at least that you can easily `product.splice(index,1)` and that will cleanly remove an item from the product array

Answer (score 0):

go through array.filter method once and then set the returned array to the localstorage again.

Answer (score 0):

This way you wont have all the product information in your cart but only the product Id and the quantity. If you need the products information in your cart you can add them in the addItemToCart function

```
const products = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Gta",
    price: 15,
    catagory: "Games",
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Call of Duty",
    price: 15,
    catagory: "Games",
},
{
id: 3,
    name: "Sims",
    price: 15,
    catagory: "Games"
},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "Razor",
    price: 15,
    catagory: "Games",
    inCart: 0
},
{
    id: 5,
    name: "Age of Empire",
    price: 15,
    catagory: "Games"
},
{
    id: 6,
    name: "Drive license",
    price: 15,
    catagory: "Games"
},
{
    id: 7,
    name: "Halo",
    price: 15,
    catagory: "Games"
}
];

let cart = {};

function loadCart() {
    let savedCart = {};
    const stringifiedCart = localStorage.getItem('cart');
    if (stringifiedCart === null) {
        return savedCart;
    }
    
    try {
        savedCart = JSON.parse(stringifiedCart);
    } catch (error) {
        localStorage.removeItem('cart');
    }
    
    return savedCart;
}

function saveCart() {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
}

function addItemToCart(itemId) {
    if (cart[itemId] == null ) {
    cart[itemId] = { quantity: 1};
  }
  
  cart[itemId].quantity++;
}

function removeItemFromCart(itemId) {
    if (cart[itemId] == null) {
    return;
  }
  
  if (cart[itemId].quantity === 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  cart[itemId].quantity--;
}

cart = loadCart();

addItemToCart(1);
addItemToCart(2);

saveCart();
```